# React js - I can't remove a component

Tags: reactjs

I have this code:

```
class ItemWrap extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { showItem: true};
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    }

    removeItem() {
        this.setState({ showItem: false });
    }

    render() {
        var item = this.state.showItem ? <Item data_items={this.props.data_items} /> : '';
        return (
            <div id="sss">
                {item}
                <button onClick={this.removeItem}>remove image</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ItemWrap;
```

On button click I remove {item}. But the button is stay. I need to remove all ItemWrap after button click.
Help me )

Comment: You've used a ternary operator to conditionally render the `item`. You can use that same operator to render the button too...

Comment: Yes, you're right.. but after that I will have empty div#sss .. I need to remove all component

Comment: you want to remove the `<div id="sss">` element ?

Comment: I want to remove all ItemWrap component after click

Comment: so the `removeItem` function should be a function of the parent component, then the parent component can choose to not display this child component

Comment: Bad architecture. Separate your state from you components and everything will become much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,removeItem function is designed for change flag of state,
and then you can use this flag to veiw whatever you want.

ex:

`if(flag)
  return (your current div);
else
  return(
    whatever you want , empty or other
  )`

Comment: No, you need to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering should be managed in the parent component, here is a possible solution

```
class ItemWrap extends Component {
   constructor() {
       super();
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div id="sss">
               <Item data_items={this.props.data_items} />
               <button onClick={this.props.onClickBtn}>remove image</button>
           </div>
       );
   }

}

export default ItemWrap;
```

then in the wrapper you can manage the rendering of ItemWrap

```
class Wrapper extends Component {
   constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = { showItem: true};
       this.removeItem= this.removeItem.bind(this);
   }

   removeItem() {
       this.setState({ showItem: false });
   }

   render() {
      return (
          <div>
              { this.state.showItem && <ItemWrapper onClickBtn={this.removeItem} /> }
          </div>
      );
   }

}

export default Wrapper;
```

Comment: Yes.. It is a good variant.. But what if I have two or more components in Wrapper.. and after click on button only one component should be remove

Comment: then you just need to have one state prop per child component

Comment: Hmm.. I don't understand how I will track - which block should be deleted

Comment: you can have multiple function `removeChild1` `removeChild2` or just one function with a parameter whichi will be the child name you want to remove